# Why doesn't Paperclip delete manually created s3 bucket folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Paperclip automatically creates a folder when posting the first file to the folder (bucket). Similarly, if I delete the last file in the folder, Paperclip also deletes the folder. The folder's name is provided via `Paperclip.interpolates`.

However, when I manually create the bucket folder on S3 (via  AWS Console), based on the interpolates or the path, I'm able to post a file via my app to the folder, but deleting the file does not delete the folder.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Amazon S3 actually stores all of your files in a flat structure with a key such as `folder/file.txt1`. The existence of the folder is only indicated by the `folder/` prefix on the file, and the folder itself does not really exist as an entity. However, the AWS console allows you to create a folder, but this concept only appears in the console itself, and has no real effect in practice.

From the Amazon S3 documentation:

> In Amazon S3 buckets and objects are the primary resources. You store objects in the bucket. It is a flat structure with no hierarchy that you see in a typical file system. However, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept using key name prefixes for objects. For example, you can create a folder called photos in the console and store an object myphoto.jpg in it. But the folder concept is supported only in the console not in Amazon S3. In Amazon S3, the object is stored in the bucket with the key name photos/myphoto.jpg. In other words, the console supports the concept of folders using the key names.

[source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html)